# (Jquery-Rich Text Editor) How can be fixed bug in rich text editor - when press enter in firefox created 'br' tag but in IE created 'p' tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, textarea, text-editor

I working on website that use [cleditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) (Jquery-Rich Text Editor).
The editor have bug - when  press enter after letter in firefox created 'br' tag but in IE created 'p' tag.

Bug reproduction: 
You can see this in their demo http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/ (enter some input end press enter (Firefox + IE ) -  see different space between lines because in IE generated 'p' tag vs firefox that genarated 'br' tag)

Update:

same question - better explanation then my: http://vanillaforums.org/discussion/13627/ie-uses-paragraph-tags-firefox-uses-br-tags/p1

please help me, what should i change for create 'br' tag also in IE instead 'p' tag.

Thanks,
Yosef

Comment: Where you able to fix the issue?

Answer (score -1):

It is not a bug. CLEditor uses standart browser api which can produce different result in different browsers and you cannot change IE behaviour but you can disable "br" generation in Mozilla by using execCommand

```
$("#input").cleditor()[0].doc.execCommand("insertBrOnReturn", false, false);
```

But content should have at least one paragraph. Only in this case firefox will generate "p".

Comment: Thank you, but your suggestion disable new line. 1. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/simple_editor.html - why yui editor not produce 'p' tag in IE??  2. I need 'br' tag - to know where new line, why should i delete it?

Comment: YUI and CKEditor doesn't use browser API, they work with their own WYSIWYG libraries to avoid browser-specific behavior. It's very hard to write something like that. You cannot get "br" tag unless you have written a library similar to library which used in YUI/CKEditor.

Comment: Ok thanks, soo how can be p tag not generated and instead generate 'br' tag in IE with IE API? (Without that It not reasonable to use cleditor)

Comment: I couldn't do that when I was researching this question. There is two way: own API for WYSIWYG or post-processing HTML code from editor. If you get it in another way, please let me know.

Comment: default IE when enter pressed not to add any tag see this demo:http://www.w3schools.com/tags/showit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea

Comment: I find out that this fix should be in future:http://groups.google.com/group/cleditor/browse_thread/thread/43925df2a11bf67e/77e178628a97e934?pli=1

Comment: WYSIWYG editors don't use TextArea. They replace TextArea with IFrame and empty HTML document with enabled "designMode". And that "designMode" works differently in IE,Opera,Chrome,Safari and FF.

Comment: If you set "insertBrOnReturn" to false in FF you will get described behavior: "enter would always start a new paragraph <p>, 
while Shift+Enter would insert a line break <br>".