# Looking for light text rich editor for enterprise website ,more light then tinymce with basic buttons for comment form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, textarea, text-editor

I am Looking for light text rich editor for enterprise website ,more light then tinymce with basic buttons for comment form.
Its important that editor will also work in IE6.
until now I try cleditor 15KB, but he have problem with IE when 'enter' press.

1. cleditor have issue -  [(Jquery-Rich Text Editor) How can be fixed bug in rich text editor - when press enter in firefox created 'br' tag but in IE created 'p' tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725049/jquery-rich-text-editor-how-can-be-fixed-bug-in-rich-text-editor-when-press)
2. YUI Editor 76kb - still prefer something lighter like cleditor 15kb and use jquery and not yui 2 framework.
3. HtmlBox editor- only for personal use according lisence and also have some bugs in simple demo.
4. markitUp editor - not show result , only in other window.
5. tinymce/ckeditor - not light editor
6. jHtmlArea - not support IE6
7. jwysiwyg - still beta version, not tested on IE6?

Update: I alreay use jquery.

please if you have good suggestion,
Thanks,
Yosef

Comment: You are aware that you can configure most editors to only show the very minimum of buttons? Is saving a few kilobytes really a priority for your target group? (It can be but it's often not, if most of the targeted users have DSL connections)

Comment: Yes, but 15kb vs 100kb(in everege) still making difference

Comment: in an enterprise environment? An intranet solution? I'm not sure how much of a difference it will make. Bear in mind that the JS will be loaded only once, and then cached.

Answer (score 2):

7kb jQuery minimalist rich text editor that works in everything as far as I know (including IE6 but I never tried it with IE9):

http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/rich-text-editor-jquery.html

Comment: Why this editor have spell error: bloc style - should be block. does he have more buttons as Italic?Can be style dialog removed from the editor+url?If does, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with using Mootools framework.  Mooeditable is a simple web-based WYSIWYG editor, written in MooTools.  Works on [A-Grade Browsers](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/) MIT license.  [Mooeditable](http://cheeaun.github.com/mooeditable/)
 As far as size goes you can build your own using the [builder](http://cheeaun.github.com/mooeditable/build.html) and take out components that you do not need.  Hope this helps.

Comment: they are all javascript you can basically add jQuery.noConflict() and use Mootools. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com)? It's licensed under flexible Open Source and commercial licenses

According to their website, you'll be able to integrate and use it inside any kind of application, making it an ideal editor for developers to provide easy and powerful solutions to their users.

The cost of the license for a single website is about $400. You did say it was for an enterprise website, so maybe the cost isn't an issue.

Comment: I already write it my review - he heavy! I dont need this monster for comment form (I know that it possible to remove buttons)